# Is there a specification of how efficient a fuel consumption / fuel burn of an airplane or engine could be?

Tags: fuel, fuel-consumption

I'm working on a project to determine whether, based on real flight data, is a flight efficient in its fuel burn/consumption. From the analysis of the flight data, i got fuel burn calculation, per phase and overall.

I want to know if there's a specification on the numbers that would help me in determining the efficiency of a flight that i can compare to, based on the fuel burn calculation of the aircraft engine from a flight, like official numbers from the manufacturer or someone similar that is reliable